# Override the existing Spring Security authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, pre-authentication

How can I override the existing Spring Security authentication by invoking a Web Service and when it's failed, need to redirect some third party login page.

For calling this authentication web service, I need to get some ServletRequest parameter and for redirection, I need to access the ServletResponse.

Therefore I need to find out some Authentication method with ServletRequest and ServletResponse parameters.

But still, I failed to find out such a ProcessingFilter or AuthenticationProvider.

According to Spring Security basic it seems I have to override the AuthenticationProvider related authenticate method.

According to use case, I have to implement the Spring Security Pre-authentication,

but the issue is PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider related 'authenticate' method only having the Authentication parameter.

**PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider**

```
public class PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider implements
        AuthenticationProvider, InitializingBean, Ordered {

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {}

}
```

As solution, is there any possibility to use custom implementation of [AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have got resolved the issue as following manner,

- Implementing a custom AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

Override the **doFilter** method

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    try { 

        // Get current Authentication object from SecurityContext
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        // Call for third party WS when the Authenticator object is null
        if (auth == null) {

            logger.debug("doFilter : Proceed the authentication"); 

            String appId = "My_APP_ID";
            String redirectURL = request.getRequestURL().toString(); 

            // Call for third party WS for get authenticate 
            if (WS_Authenticator.isAuthenticated(appId, redirectURL)) { 

                // Successfully authenticated
                logger.debug("doFilter : WS authentication success");

                // Get authenticated username 
                String userName = WS_Authenticator.getUserName();               

                // Put that username to request
                request.setAttribute("userName", userName);

            } else {

                String redirectURL = WS_Authenticator.getAuthorizedURL();
                logger.debug("doFilter : WS authentication failed");
                logger.debug("doFilter : WS redirect URL : " + redirectURL);

                ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(redirectURL);

                // Return for bypass the filter chain 
                return;
            }   

        } else {
            logger.debug("doFilter : Already authenticated"); 
        }   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("doFilter: " + e.getMessage());            
    }

    super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    return;
}
```

Override the **getPreAuthenticatedCredentials** method

```
@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {

    // Get authenticated username
    String[] credentials = new String[1];
    credentials[0] = (String) request.getAttribute("userName");

    return credentials;
}
```

- Implementing a CustomAuthenticationUserDetailsServiceImpl

Override the **loadUserDetails** method

```
public class CustomAuthenticationUserDetailsServiceImpl implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {

    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationUserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDataService userDataService;

    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Get authenticated username 
        String[] credentials = (String[]) token.getCredentials();
        String userName = credentials[0];

        try {

            // Get user by username
            User user = userDataService.getDetailsByUserName(userName); 

            // Get authorities username             
            List<String> roles = userDataService.getRolesByUserName(userName);          
            user.setCustomerAuthorities(roles);
            return user;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("loadUserDetails: User not found! " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```